# Relations derived from ist law of thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility

[image]

In the 5th point given in the image, it is mentioned that this relation is applicable for both reversible and **irreversible** processes, since the parameters involved are state functions i.e independent of path. This particular relation is obtained by substituting dq =Tds. However, the relation dq=Tds is valid only for reversible process, since for an irreversible process there is the possibility of entropy generation and hence T**ds** will not be an accurate measure of dq. So how is the use of relation 5th justified for irreversible process? I partly understand the 5th point, but cannot fully grasp it, can someone point out an example/situation where such an relation is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is already written in the sentence after the equation and also the remark in the 6th point is relevant. Maybe some additional explanation would had been in order.

The key point is that, although the relation between *process quantities* like Q or W are path dependent, as soon as you write a relation where only *state functions* appear, that relation becomes independent on the path, thus, if you have a differential relations like eqn. 5,  one can choose whatever reversible path joining the same initial and final state to get finite variations. What should be clear is that, although $dS$, $dU$ and $dV$ are the variations between the initial and final states, there is no way to identify $-pdV$ with the work and $TdS$ with the heat exchanged in an irreversible process between the same two states.

An illustration of this point can be done by examining the [Joule experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion) where an irreversible expansion of a gas is performed inside an isolated container of fixed total volume. In that case, the irreversible process takes place at $Q=0$ and $W=0$ (adiabatic and fixed walls). However there is a change of entropy (the process is irreversible) which can be evaluated by using a different (reversible) process.